# Book where alien empire takes over earth and moves humans to planets named after the continents

Tags: story-identification, aliens, empire

This book started with the main character falling into the ocean, I believe. I also think he was in a battle in WWII.
An alien empire has taken over The Earth and moved humans to planets named after the continents, except the humans didn't know they were moved. This future has a lot of dimensions where you can store your stuff, no matter how big it is, and retrieve it later.

Our hero, one of the more common superheroes, like Captain America or something and for the life of me I can't remember who, gets involved in the overthrow of this alien empire which is using Earth as it's capital.
This is an older book as I read it somewhere around 2002. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: kinda want to read whatever this is now.  Could you clarify if you actually mean captain america as in you remember this being a comic book or was it a captain america like character?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure. It's been so long. I just remember I recognized the character and I believe the book started with him having been in a battle (WWII) and an explosion occurred after which he found himself in the future. I really wish I could remember more, it would be so much easier to identify!

Answer (score 3):

The series I believe you are referring to is [Starhawk, by Mack Maloney.](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57282-starhawk) The series revolves around a fighter pilot who wakes up in the future on a deserted planet and is discovered by imperial explorers. The series then revolves around him trying to figure what has happened in the meantime. The events the poster is referring to mainly occur in the second book "Planet America" where he discovers an artificial star system containing a small planet of each of the nations of earth.

They're frozen in a sort of utopian 50s era setting and unknowingly trapped there by a strange force of mercenaries who destroy the population of a planet when they begin to develop early space travel. The third book is where the hero learns that the early leaders of the Galactic Empire created the star system and that the emperors are likely partially alien which explains their long life spans. It's suggested they made some sort of deal with aliens from outside the galaxy in exchange for their power. The series just gets crazier from there. The next books have ghosts, angels and demons, Space Soviets, Saturn as a massive futuristic amusement park, UFOs, etc.

It's not bad though, it's kind of fun and like modern pulp sci-fi.

Comment: Can you provide more details that suggest similarity? We don't mind spoilers as the OP is usually looking for something they've already seen!

Comment: Hope that gives you a better idea of the series.